# Windows Spotlight to show images from a specific country for a lock screen?

Tags: images, lock-screen, windows-spotlight

How to make Windows Spotlight only show images from a specific country for my lock screen?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no option to choose which images are
shown using Windows Spotlight.

You can train Spotlight somewhat by clicking your likes
and dislikes, but there's no way to pick a different set
of trained preferences.
This is done via the little camera icon displayed on the
top-right of the screen.
Clicking the "Not a fan" option will also switch to a
new image.

If you would like to erase the acquired preferences and start
anew, see the article
[How to reset Windows Spotlight feature in Windows 11/10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/reset-windows-spotlight).